# Issues writing ampersand into a file from windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, ampersand

For reasons outside the scope of this question, I need to create a batch file dynamically from another batch file.  In essence, I have a serious of commands like so:

```
echo some command > newfile.cmd
echo more commands >> newfile.cmd
echo and more commands >> newfile.cmd
```

All of this works correctly except one specific thing.  One of the commands is this:

```
myprogram.exe >> %LOG_FILE% 2>&1
```

For the life of me I can't get this to output correctly into the new batch file.  I've tried all sorts of options with escaping ampersand with ^ char, putting the whole thing into a double-quoted string assignment, double-escaping - pretty much everything!  The best I managed is to output

```
myprogram.exe >> %LOG_FILE% 2>&
```

however everything else is truncated.  How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: If the log file variable needs to be sent to the batch as is as well, then you need to escape the `%` as well by doubling them. `echo myprogram.exe ^>^> %%LOG_FILE%% 2^>^&1`

Answer (score 0):

You would escape problem characters, like redirection `<`|`>`, and ampersands, `&`, using a caret, `^`:

```bash
@(
    echo some command
    echo myprogram.exe 1^>^>"%LOG_FILE%" 2^>^&1
    echo and (even^) more commands
) 1>"newfile.cmd"
```

If you use this methodology, by redirecting just once, instead of the slower multiple times, you'll also have to escape nested closing parentheses, `)` with a caret too, `^`,  as shown above.